# The program crashed when executed on Visual Studio but it ran properly on cpp.sh website

Tags: c++

guys! Down here is the code that I have for my Bank assignment. It ran well when I chose Case 1 to check the Balance. However, when I chose Case 2 for Depositing, the program crashes right after entering the amount of deposit. I looked through the code but I'm not sure where the problem came from. However, the program seems to run ok when executed on cpp.sh website and only crashes on Visual Studio. Is it because of my code or my compiler?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class account {

private:
    double AccountActivity[200];
    double balance;
    int numTransactions;

public:

    //declaration
};

void account::test() {

    account a;
    int choice;
    bool menu = true;
    double amount = 0;

    while (menu = true) {
        choice = a.getUserChoice();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            a.print();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\n\nPlease enter the amount of deposit: " << endl;
            cin >> amount;
            a.deposit(amount);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\n\nPlease enter the amount of withdrawal: " << endl;
            cin >> amount;
            a.withdraw(amount);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "The largest deposit is: " << a.getLargest() << endl;
        default:
            cout << "Please choose from 1 to 4" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

}

int account::getUserChoice() {
    //do something
}
double account::getLargest()
{
    //do something
}

void account::print() {
    cout << "Your balance is: $" << balance;
    cout << "\n\n";
}

account::account() {
    balance = 0;
}

void account::deposit(double amount) {
    if (numTransactions < 200)
    {
        AccountActivity[numTransactions] = amount;
        numTransactions++;
        balance += amount;
    }
}

void account::withdraw(double amount) {
    if (balance < amount)
        cout << "Insufficient balance" << endl;
    else
    {
        if (amount >= 0 && numTransactions < 200)
        {
            AccountActivity[numTransactions] = -amount;
            numTransactions++;
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: What's the run-time error its giving? You can find it by pressing continue on the pop-up telling you that the program needed to be terminated.

Comment: *Is it because of my code or my compiler?* -- Do you really think that a compiler used by thousands of people, and maybe thousands of companies around the world would get something wrong as trivial as your program?  It is your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numTransactions` is not initialized. Using an uninitialized value to index into an array is undefined behavior.

In your account constructor `account::account()` set `numTransactions` to 0

Oh yeah: `while (menu = true) {` try `while(menu)` - but then you don't change `menu` inside the loop so you might as well make it `while(1) {`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I finally got it fixed in correct way.